# DependencyResolver Asp.net 5.0

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I'm migrating my site, from asp.net 4.5 to 5.0. Previously, I used `System.Web.Mvc` to get `DependencyResolver.SetResolve` to register dependencies. Is there any publication or documentation that can point me to the new `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` version?

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html

That's official documentation for dependency injection for asp.net 5.

Dependency injection is now built into asp.net 5 but you are free to use other libraries like autofac. The default one is working fine for me.

In your starup class, you have a method like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    //IServiceCollection acts like a container and you 
    //can register your classes like this:

    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.Singleton<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddScoped<ICharacterRepository, CharacterRepository>();

}
```

These are some [Service Lifetimes and Registration Options](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options)

Comment: `protected virtual void RegisterDependencies(QuizConfig config)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            var container = builder.Build();
            **DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));**
        }`

This is in a Library.

Comment: What library ? I dont understand what you are trying to say

Comment: I created a library, that my main project uses.