# ASP.NET Core DependencyResolver

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC 5 is possible to obtain some dependency through `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<T>()`. Is there something similar in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: The `DependencyResolver.Current` has been replaced with the `IServiceProvider` abstraction.

Comment: OK. But is there something like ServiceProvider.Current.GetService<T>()? I want to be able to obtain a service without the need to inject it.

Comment: There isn't, and that's actually a good thing. What you are trying to do is a bad practice.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, there is. In ASP.NET Core 1.0.0, the services available within a request from `HttpContext` are exposed through the RequestServices collection<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
this.HttpContext.RequestServices
```

You can use the GetService method to retrieve the dependencies by specifying the type of the dependency:

```
this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ISomeService));
```

Generally, you shouldn’t use these properties directly, preferring instead to request the types your classes you require via your class’s constructor, and letting the framework inject these dependencies. This yields classes that are easier to test and are more loosely coupled.

<sub>[1] https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#request-services</sub>

Comment: It was removed in RC2 https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/118

Comment: Correct, it was made available on ASP.NET Core 1.0.0. I should have mentioned the version in the reply to make it clearer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 15):

If you really need it, you can write own one. First - create `AppDependencyResolver` class.

```
public class AppDependencyResolver
{
    private static AppDependencyResolver _resolver;

    public static AppDependencyResolver Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_resolver == null)
                throw new Exception("AppDependencyResolver not initialized. You should initialize it in Startup class");
            return _resolver;
        }
    }

    public static void Init(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _resolver = new AppDependencyResolver(services);
    }

    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService<T>();
    }

    private AppDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
}
```

Please note that `_serviceProvider.GetService<T>();` only available if you add `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`. That namespace will be available if you add `"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0"` to your `project.json`.
Than you should call `Init` method in your `startup` class. For example

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        AppDependencyResolver.Init(app.ApplicationServices);
        //all other code
```

After that you can use it anywhere, same as `DependencyResolver.Current`. But my suggestion - use it only if no other choice left.

Comment: One of the major things about Dependency injection is avoid using static (singleton) instances.

Comment: As I said, use it only if no other choice left. If you can inject it in controller or filter - it is better choise. If you need some background task it is better to create new scope and use it to resolve dependency. But sometimes in legacy code you need to resolve some singeleton service and you have no time to rewrite such code - this method may be used.

Comment: "_If you really need it_" -- how are you mocking tests that might require DI without it?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the way that worked for me in .Net core 2.0

```
public ViewResult IndexWithServiceLocatorPattern([FromServices]ProductTotalizer totalizer)
{
    var repository = (IRepository)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IRepository));
    ViewBag.HomeController = repository.ToString();
    ViewBag.Totalizer = totalizer.repository.ToString();
    return View("Index", repository.Products);
}
```

If I have to do it with classical way, It would be like below.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository repo;

    /// <summary>
    /// MVC receives an incoming request to an action method on the Home controller. 
    /// MVC asks the ASP.NET service provider component for a new instance of the HomeController class.
    /// The service provider inspects the HomeController constructor and discovers that it has a dependency on the IRepository interface. 
    /// The service provider consults its mappings to find the implementation class it has been told to use for dependencies on the IRepository interface. 
    /// The service provider creates a new instance of the implementation class. 
    /// The service provider creates a new HomeController object, using the implementation object as a constructor argument.
    /// The service provider returns the newly created HomeController object to MVC, which uses it to handle the incoming HTTP request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="repo"></param>
    public HomeController(IRepository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Using Action Injection
    ///  MVC uses the service provider to get an instance of the ProductTotalizer class and provides it as an
    ///  argument when the Index action method is invoked.Using action injection is less common than standard
    ///  constructor injection, but it can be useful when you have a dependency on an object that is expensive to
    ///  create and that is required in only one of the action methods defined by a controller
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="totalizer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ViewResult Index([FromServices]ProductTotalizer totalizer)
    {
        ViewBag.Total = totalizer.repository.ToString();
        ViewBag.HomeCotroller = repo.ToString();
        return View(repo.Products);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Service available in Asp.net core, its within `HttpContext`

```
this.HttpContext.RequestServices
```

By using this service, it is possible to get service. and also you can use GetService method to retrieve the dependencies by specifying the type of the dependency:

```
this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ISomeService));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are  extension methods for IServiceProvider: GetService, GetRequiredService and GetServices. All have generic and non-generic versions.
In Asp.Net Core web project you can obtain reference to IServiceProvider via DI or from IApplicationBuilder.
In Console app you should create your own instance of IServiceProvider and store reference somewhere

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
...
ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a good start:

That's official documentation for dependency injection for asp.net 5.

Dependency injection is now built into asp.net 5 but you are free to use other libraries like autofac. The default one is working fine for me.

In your starup class, you have a method like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    //IServiceCollection acts like a container and you 
    //can register your classes like this:

    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.Singleton<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddScoped<ICharacterRepository, CharacterRepository>();

}
```

From:

[DependencyResolver Asp.net 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236560/dependencyresolver-asp-net-5-0)

Answer (score 0):

I also want to add to the main answer,
In razor view pages we can use @inject directive for DI. It will retrieve the targeted services to view pages on Asp.Net core, like this

```
@inject XYZ.Web.Services.CurrencyService currencyService;
```